# RESTful webservice + MongoDB (@Netbeans)

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, netbeans

I'm trying to develop a RESTful webservice to put and get data to/from a Mongo database. For creating this webservices, I'm following the netbeans tutorial https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html[1] .
The thing is, even with the Mongo DB plugin installed on netbeans, the db doesn't appear on the data sources when trying to create new RESTful Web Services from Database.
Any ideas on how to make this work?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial deals with JDBC data sources. Mongo DB is a non-relational DB, or NOSQL DB. You cannot use is via JDBC. Are you sure you are following the tutorial correctly? You may want to use MySQL. Then it will appear in the list.

Of course you can use Mongo DB. But not via JDBC. And there will be no data source displayed.